# How check at lease one checkbox is checked inside ASP.NET repeater control in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In my asp.net website; i have REPEATER control having child control checklistbox , dynamically generates in code behind.

I would like to know how can i write javascript function where i have to check at least one checkbox should be checked.

Ho can i acheive? Please Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap the list of checkboxes in a container (e.g. a `<div>`) with a known ID:

```
<div id="myCheckboxes">
  <input type="checkbox" ...>
  <!-- ... -->
  <input type="checkbox" ...>
</div>
```

And then in JavaScript do:

```
function isOneChecked(containerId) {
  var myDiv = document.getElementByID(containerId);
  if (myDiv != null) {
    var checkBoxes = myDiv.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");

    for (var i=0; i<checkBoxes.length; i++) {
      if (checkBoxes[i].checked == true) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

and call it as:

```
if (isOneChecked("myCheckboxes")) {
  // whatever
}
```

Comment: In my case i am using checklistbox inside REPEATER control. Does it require to find repeater control first. Then find checklist? How?

Comment: @Hermant: OK, let me rephrase my first sentence for you: *You could wrap the **repeater** in a container (e.g. a `<div>`)...*

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery way:

```
if($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0){
  alert('At least one check box is checked')
}
```

P.S. If it not a problem use frameworks, you can choose form variety of them(jQuery, Prototype, MooTools, Dojo etc.). They will make your life easier and your javascript code more crossbrowser compatible.

Comment: Limiting it to a certain container would be necessary in jQuery, too.

Comment: Yeah, I'd add the asp:repeaters clientID into the jQuery selector:    $('#<%=repeaterID.ClientId%> input[type=checkbox]:checked')

Comment: You are both right, but the code above is just an example for the jQ way, there is no original html provided so I have skipped the container id part to make it more clear.

Comment: Your answer is right but for completeness, if the asker doesn't know how to add the repeated selector in, I thought it'd be nice to know. I didn't want to add another answer basically duplicating yours. On second look, are you sure your logic is right? Shouldn't it be length < 1 ?

Comment: "at least one checkbox should be checked" so the number of checked boxes must be greater than 0, am I right?